# Get Twitter User Details without Authentication

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have noticed some Twitter Applications manage to get a particular users Location, Name, Profile Image etc using just the twitter username?

Hows is this possible?

I ask because I have not come across any where in the Twitter docs on how you can do this. I can get a users details myself using oAuth when the user provides my app permission but thats it.

Would be grateful if this could be cleared. I hope its not the use of CURL as this is not a good idea in my eyes. If there is another way, is there a PHP implementation that I could use.

Thank you for any help.

### Update

I did not know that existed! Is there a PHP wrapper or class someone has written to use that ? Sorry, I am complete noob and I relay on wrappers and simple function calls!

Comment: Updated my answer with relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

It's returned by the [users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) call from the API.

For example:
http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=dougw

The [API wiki](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php) lists a PHP library FWIW.

Comment: errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}